# Rails 4 equivalent of Rails 3 'Model.all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3 if I wanted to hit the db I'd take .all on the end of a query. This is useful for when I'm doing things like refreshing cache on writes (so reads always hit cache).

Now in Rails 4, Model.all returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object (ie doesn't hit the db). What is the best way to get it actually go to the db and return the records specified?

Comment: @Bigxiang: ["The return value is the relation itself, not the records."](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load).

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. I think "to_a" will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Model.all.to_a` in Rails 4 will give the same result as `Modal.all` in Rails 3.

Amend:

@Bigxiang, pointed out in his comment to try `Model.all.load`, this method for certain hits the database but still returns an ActiveRecordRelation.  And basically to get a similar functionality as `Model.all` from "Rails 3", you can call `to_a` on the returned `ActiveRecordRelation`.

Comment: It's also worth that if you already have an ActiveRecord::Relation you don't need the `.all`. eg: If you have `Model.where(name: "John").all` in Rails 3.2, you can replace it with `Model.where(name: "John").to_a` rather than `Model.where(name: "John").all.to_a` in Rails 4

Comment: Hi, Can you explain the difference between the `.all` and `.scoped` in rails 3. I know `.scoped` is deprecated in rails 4. But will be really appreciate what is the actual difference. Thanks

Comment: @Vinay, apologies for late response. Haven't had a chance to get into SO lately. Well the basic difference is `Model.all` returns an array and `Model.scoped` returns `AR::Relation`. With `Model.scoped` you can chain queries such as filtering using `where`, e.g. `Model.scoped.where(...)` whereas `Model.all.where(..)` would fail because `Model.all` returns an array. Hope this clarifies your confusion.