# Rails Rendering the data from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am a newbie in rails. I am trying to render the data from the DB and display. I have been almost succeeded but It was not displaying the data as shown in the image below.

```
Companies List
Name    Place           
                  **VIEW**(Click of this is working and navigating nothing is displaying)

ADD New Company
```

And Here is my controllers code:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @companies = Company.all


   end


  def show
    @companies = Company.find(params[:id])

  end


  def new
    @companies = Company.new
end

  def create
    @companies = Company.new(params[:Company])
    if @companies.save

      flash[:success] = "Welcome to skillable"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end



end
```

Here is my view code index.html.erb

```
<h1>Companies List</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @companies.each do |companies| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= companies.name %></td>
    <td><%= companies.place %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', companies %></td>
        <% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'ADD New Company', new_company_path %>
```

So can anyone tell me what is my problem. why it is not showing. please I am unable to figure out my problem.

Comment: In the `@companies.each` loop you are not closing the row. Before the `<% end %>` tag you should put a `</tr>`. Could this be it?

Comment: No it is not the problem.

Comment: Are there any values in @companies?

Comment: Ya it getting the values from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in index page I would write:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= company.name %></td>
    <td><%= company.place %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', company %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

this will show a list of companies. Next, a click on **VIEW** would take you for ex to: `/companies/1` where `1` is the id of a `company`. That means you'll find company by id in show action of companies controller:

```
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
end
```

**see how I call variable** - `@company`, not `@companies` cause I assume in `show.html.erb` you have used `@company` variable (or if it's created by scaffold it's for sure `@company`), also this is the page for one `company` only and it would be more appropriate to call it with singular (company not companies).

Doing all of the above you will use in show page for ex:

```
<%= @company.name %>
```

---

**P.S. 1** You have the same naming issue for `new` and `create` actions, I would do it like this:

```
 def new
   @company = Company.new
 end
```

this will let me use this variable in a form like:

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

and:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])
  if @company.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to skillable"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**P.S. 2**

to check if you have something in db - open `rails console`:

```
your/project/path/ rails c

x.x.x-pxxx :001 > Company.first
  Company Load (18.2ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

if result will be `nil`, means you have nothing in db, else - you have records inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Company.all.to_a` in your controller index method.

Possible duplicate of this question: [rails 4 equivalent of rails 3 model all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456536/rails-4-equivalent-of-rails-3-model-all)

Comment: ya it is still the same

Comment: In your question it isn't clear where it is not displaying. In the index or in the show method? Please be more precise. If it's in the show method then your path variable in the view link is wrong. It should be something like company_path(id).

Comment: Are there values stored in the db table companies? Use pgphpadmin or sqlite manager to see your database table entries. If there are none, then nothing can be displayed.