# Returning the original relation in a class method called on a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, collections

I have a class method on a model called `order_by_ids(ids)` that is called by an ActiveRecord Relation.  Below is an example of its usage:

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).order_by_ids([2,1,3])
```

...will return Users 1, 2, and 3 in the order of: [2,1,3]

I would like for it to return the original relation (essentially doing nothing) if passed an empty array.

The following returns the entire class, not just the relation it's called on:

```
return self unless ids.present?
```

The following works 100%, but it seems inelegant.  Also, I think it runs an unnecessary query (seems slower in the console anyway):

```
return where.not(id: nil) unless ids.present?
```

Is there a quick way to just return the relation it's called on?  I could theoretically make it a scope, but I've been taught to avoid scopes with arguments (see [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) guide for reference).

Note: I am using Rails 3, so `all` returns an array.  I'm essentially looking for a Rails 4 version of `all`.

Comment: Why have you been taught to avoid scopes with arguments? What was the reason for this guideline?

Comment: @spickermann Added reference to the Ruby On Rails guide.  Mind you, that doesn't necessarily make the guideline correct, just letting you know where I got it.

Comment: But the same guide tells you in the next [section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-conditionals) how to solve the problem: Use a scope with an argument...

Comment: @mrmicrowaveoven did `all` work for you?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Not with my version of rails.  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The following should preserve the upstream scope chain (returning `all`, not `self`):

```
return all if ids.none?
```

P.S. Named scopes is a perfectly accepted and conventional way of dealing with queries.

Comment: So I'm guessing this will return a Relation on Rails 4 and later.  My company's current version of rails converts this into an array.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456536/rails-4-equivalent-of-rails-3-model-all.  Is there a more universal way of doing this?

Comment: @mrmicrowaveoven which version of Rails is your company using?